# Wireless Problem WITH ASUS K450J

Tags: wireless

Hello i am new at Ubuntu and recently installed it.. There was no problem until i found my wireless connection wasn't working. What do i do? I tried to enable it but my button goes straight to disable. I tried to install a wireless driver in the Downloads & Updates but it says i don't need to install any additional wireless driver. So what do i do to troubleshoot and or what do i do to fix it:

> Computer: ASUS K450J   OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Please help!

Comment: Please give output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 && rfkill list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer is doing the following command:

```
 echo "blacklist acer-wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf
```

Reboot after the command.

Comment: And what `acer-wmi` has to do on an ASUS laptop?

Comment: You probably used my command too, but did not reboot after that.

Comment: I did reboot but didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this can be solved by running

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
```

and reboot.

This is if wireless is always blocked by rfkill. In some cases wireless drivers should be installed.