# WiFi (Intel Wireless 3165 [8086:3165]) not working on new install

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu on a new HP Windows 10 laptop, but the wifi is not working. Nothing happens when I click **Enable Wifi** and **Wifi Networks** is greyed out. Wifi works ok in Windows.

Wireless info is below.

I note that `rfkill` shows a soft block,

```
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

But `sudo rfkill unblock wifi` doesn't change anything.

Any suggestions on how to resolve?

#### wireless info START

Report from: 21 Mar 2016 10:12 GMT +0000

Booted last: 21 Mar 2016 09:40 GMT +0000

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

release

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

kernel

Linux 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

desktop

Ubuntu

lspci

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8074]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:57c4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

PCMCIA card info

rfkill

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

lsmod

acer_wmi               20480  0 
hp_wmi                 16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
iwlmvm                290816  0 
mac80211              729088  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               204800  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              540672  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
wmi                    20480  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
video                  36864  2 i915,acer_wmi

interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
          inet addr:192.168.1.18  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8911 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7349744 (7.3 MB)  TX bytes:455446 (455.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search Home

network managers

Installed:

```
NetworkManager
```

Running:

root      3502     1  0 10:06 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

NetworkManager info

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
  WEP Encryption:  yes
  WPA Encryption:  yes
  WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points
- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:

  Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes
  Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
  Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
  Address:         192.168.1.18
  Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
  Gateway:         192.168.1.1

  DNS:             192.168.1.1

NetworkManager.state

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

NetworkManager profiles

iw reg get

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

iwlist channels

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

iwlist scan

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

module infos

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation 
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     3BBD88D7E8252B90136F463
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     FBF6EA073A00B4F3836226E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation 
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-12.ucode
srcversion:     75997E53B9CC3BD2CA79F3B
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     7982686FBE8064A87E02753
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

module parameters

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

/etc/modules

lp
rtc

modprobe options

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

rc.local

exit 0

pm-utils

udev rules

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
 PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
 PCI device 0x8086:0x3165 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

dmesg

[   26.999775] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[   27.075037] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   28.028036] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[   28.104823] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  331.502398] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[  331.581113] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  341.650821] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[  341.728842] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  356.965279] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[  357.043941] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1086.794294] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link up
[ 1086.794344] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 1212.082820] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[ 1212.160425] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1538.489354] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[ 1538.489481] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 1540.096595] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link up
[ 1540.096620] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 1548.968005] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[ 1549.048818] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1555.640263] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[ 1555.726240] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1676.304184] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[ 1676.383070] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

#### wireless info END ############

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless Problem WITH ASUS K450J](http://askubuntu.com/questions/622688/wireless-problem-with-asus-k450j)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot change soft block setting to "no" for AR9287 Wireless Network](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62730/cannot-change-soft-block-setting-to-no-for-ar9287-wireless-network)

Comment: You have to blacklist the acer_wmi module - see https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/240287 and you should probably file a bug reprot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be temporarily fixed by

```
sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi
```

To fix it permanently you need to blacklist this module.

But a better solution is to report this issue to Launchpad to get it fixed upstream.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have resolved it, and adding "blacklist acer_wmi" to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. I don't know what Launchpad is.

Comment: Launchpad is where you report Ubuntu bugs. Run `ubuntu-bug linux` with not blacklisted module and create a bur report. This way it can be fixed for your laptop model without blacklisting.