# No Internet, but WIFI working - Ubuntu 17.04 on Asus TP200SA

Tags: wireless, internet, connection

I installed Ubuntu 17.04. It connects to the WIFI but the Internet does not work. I have an ASUS TP200SA With Ubuntu 16.04 it worked perfect.

Can not use Internet, but can connect to wifi - Ubuntu 17.04 on Asus TP200SA

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 03 Nov 2016 22:08 MSK +0300

Booted last: 03 Nov 2016 00:00 MSK +0300

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-19-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 6 17:04:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0781:5590 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2188:0ae1  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3491 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57e6 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           344064  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    28672  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              782336  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              602112  3 mac80211,ath,ath10k_core
wmi                    16384  1 asus_wmi
video                  40960  3 asus_wmi,int3406_thermal,i915

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback  brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp2s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
    inet 192.168.0.103/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
       valid_lft 6844sec preferred_lft 6844sec
    inet6 fe80::/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XXX"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point:    
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:56   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.103 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1070     1  1 22:02 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath10k_pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.10.0-19-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     XXX
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       1e837ce9-c2d2-4030-81e9-6a456e657cc2
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   1e837ce9-c2d2-4030-81e9-6a456e657cc2 | XXX
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.103/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1478206963
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.103
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

SSID                BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
XXX             Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  61      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  yes     * 
XXX          Infra  4     2427 MHz  54 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  --         no        
SS XXXXX    Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  --         no        
XXXX          Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  --         no        
  XXXX      Infra  7     2442 MHz  54 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  --         no        
XXXXX          Infra  60    5300 MHz  54 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  --         no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/XXX-1e837ce9-c2d2-4030-81e9-6a456e657cc2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=XXX | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=XXX
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/XXX]] (600 root)
[connection] id=XXX | type=wifi | permissions=user:ubuntu:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=XXX
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Moscow (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.3 GHz (Channel 60)

wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"XXX"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000264a72db17
                    Extra: Last beacon: 92ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: 
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"FFFFF"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000036a7949d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 6276ms ago
          Cell 03 - Address: 
                    Channel:60
                    Frequency:5.3 GHz (Channel 60)
                    Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"XDF"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000037f5194f4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3840ms ago
          Cell 04 - Address: 
                    Channel:7
                    Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                    Quality=20/70  Signal level=-90 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"  A AAFAQ-NET-12"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000001c88e22d2
                    Extra: Last beacon: 6096ms ago

##### module infos ######################

[ath10k_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac WLAN PCIe/AHB devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     50E531406EF702B9976A8A9
depends:        ath10k_core
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)

[ath10k_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac wireless LAN cards.
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     1B2C9C18ACF805C04DCA414
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           uart_print:Uart target debugging (bool)
parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for calibration in testmode (bool)
parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)
parm:           rawmode:Use raw 802.11 frame datapath (bool)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     4B8612B6FF71DD27AE8CE67
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     6FCDB39CB1DCCA0C9A450B2
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     0ADFC23D0B6BCD6916160E7
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath10k_pci]
irq_mode: 0
reset_mode: 0

[ath10k_core]
cryptmode: 0
debug_mask: 0
rawmode: N
skip_otp: N
uart_print: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   80.837828] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   81.150511] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   81.150548] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   81.160059] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 target 0x05020000 chip_id 0x003820ff sub 1a3b:2231
[   81.160065] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   81.160765] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[   81.264561] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 93da0176
[   83.826131] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   83.833863] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6a
[   83.833866] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   83.833869] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   83.833870] ath: Regpair used: 0x6a
[   83.880104] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   84.348659] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 5 times)
[   93.359619] wlp2s0: authenticate with 
[   93.395340] wlp2s0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[   93.397647] wlp2s0: authenticated
[   93.399774] wlp2s0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[   93.405206] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
[   93.416109] wlp2s0: associated
[   93.416202] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Also if I connect my Phone via Bluetooth-Connection, Internet is not working and via USB-Internet also not.

Sorry I had to ask this Question again and delete my old one, because I posted something wrong.

Comment: This also not worked for my case https://askubuntu.com/a/653727/671111 Do you have any other ideas? @chili555

Comment: I made this: https://askubuntu.com/a/748497/671111
And then internet is working. But he says, that this is just a temporaly solution. Hope to reach a permanent.

Comment: @CelticWarrior No it is not.  The problem here is, that the wifi is connected, but still no internet access.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. And yet the OP claims it worked: https://askubuntu.com/a/905146/589808 and that's the one and only reason I flagged it as such. ;-)

Comment: I see,  I got the same problem but in my case it is after upgrading to 17.04, and the linked solution doesn't apply.

Comment: I have the same problem. As a workaround I edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to use `8.8.8.8` as nameserver and it works. I guess this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Let's amend just one file. Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Use [nano or kate or leafpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913609/what-are-the-default-text-editors-in-different-flavours-of-ubuntu/913637#913637) if you don't have the text editor gedit. Add lines:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0
```

Save and close file then reboot.

I also suggest that you check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.