# Wifi adapter (Intel Corporation Wireless 3165) disconnects frequently

Tags: iwlwifi

My Wifi adapter disconnects every 5-10 minutes. I have read that this is a common issue for some users, specially if your card is Intel.

Some information about my machine:

```
$ lspci|grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux rocket 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

**Log**

This is the output of `dmesg` just before disconnection:

```
[ 1042.712511] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 8c:0c:90:08:dd:4c by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

and this is the output after restarting the adapter with `sudo service network-manager restart`:

```
[ 2192.019982] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 2192.020067] wlp2s0: associate with 8c:0c:90:08:dd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 2192.031051] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 8c:0c:90:08:dd:4c (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 2192.031802] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2192.082048] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 8c:0c:90:08:dd:4c
```

**Attempted solutions**

Many users suggest to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` to disable power management by adding this line:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 power_save=0 power_level=5 bt_coex_active=0` at the end of
```

[Others](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748495/wifi-intel-wireless-3165-80863165-not-working-on-new-install) suggest to remove the module `acer_wmi`:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi
```

[Others](https://superuser.com/questions/974017/ubuntu-wlan0-authenticates-and-then-drops) [suggest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253933/wifi-iw-reg-set-us-has-no-effect) to define the `REGDOMAIN` variable in `/etc/default/crda`:

```
sudo iw reg set US
sudo sed -i 's/^REG.*=$/&US/' /etc/default/crda
```

It also may be due to [having two instances](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=161920) of `wpa_supplicant`:

```
systemctl list-units
```

If so, you can remove one of them:

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
systemctl disable net-auto-wired.service
systemctl disable net-auto-wireless.service
```

Finally, I tried to boot from an USB with Ubuntu 19.04, but the problem persists, the log messages are the same as above.

Anyway, I have tried these approaches, but they do not solve the problem, the wifi adapter disconnects randomly, always showing this message in the log:

```
[ 1042.712511] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 8c:0c:90:08:dd:4c by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Comment: @Nmath, It seems a problem related to the Ubuntu version. I downgrade from 18.04/19.04 to 16.04 and it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: did a fresh ubuntu 20.04 install on an old laptop with a Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 22
00 BGN card. the modprobe.d/iwlconf change fixed this issue for me. the country setting also may have been needed

Comment: this seems like the most comprehensive list of possible solution so far, thanks for posting this.

Comment: Been battling this for months then gave up and used a USB wifi dongle (D-Link System AirPlus G DWL-G122 Wireless Adapter(rev.C1) [Ralink RT2571W]). Then my wifi disconnected again :(